# Any way to make "find references" work for web methods?

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I'm looking for a way to find references to a web method in other code that may use it.  Right-click and choose find references doesn't make it through the wsdl interface to other classes in my solution that reference those web methods.  This is part of a clean-up effort - I'm trying to remove outdated/old/unused methods.

I can search by name but its not the same as searching by signature.

I realize that normally, webmethods/webservices could be called by other applications remotely but that's not the case with this webservice/these webmethods.  My app is the only app calling them.  I'm not asking to find references existing outside my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this from the web service implementation, but you can go to the generated proxy (you may have to "show all files" from within the solution explorer to see the .cs file) and do a find references from there.

Comment: Yeah, didn't think of using the Reference.cs file.  Thanks!